# Missing pixels with Intel Integrated Graphics

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, graphics, intel-graphics

On the following pictures below this text, there are some missing pixels on the title bar of every application. Here's a example on the Terminal application:

[image: see the right part of the title bar]

[image: see the right part of the title bar]

And from VLC:

[image: Look at these lines.]

Comment: You are using the tag "intel-graphics". Does that mean you are using Intel integrated graphics?